# How to change WebService code behind class dynamically?

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I'm facing an issue with different versions of a Web Service.

Because there are several versions of the Web service, sometimes the parameters are changed and/or WebMethods are added and removed.

I want to have a single asmx file, but depending on the client installation (the version they are running), be able to change the code behind of the asmx at runtime.

Instead of having different asmx per version, just have one asmx file that dynamically can load the code behind with the accurate version. In this case I do have a V1Methods.cs, V2Methods.cs, V10Methods.cs

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#"  Class="DynamicClass" %>
```

If the customer is running Version2, the asmx code behind class should be V2Methods.cs and so on.

Is it possible?

Comment: How do you know what version your client is running? Typical REST API will use a URL scheme to differentiate versions.

Comment: In this case, there is going to be a configuration file, during the setup, user will be challenged to enter the version of the product (which is tied to the API version or WSDL). Namely, I'm trying to achieve that one size fits all by having a single EndPoint. And the main problem is that there are HUGE changes in the WSDL between versions.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: @JohnSaunders while I agree with your point of view, the idea is to continue using the legacy services because the clients (which are even      eclipse addins and visual studio plugins) are designed to support them. However, it's hard that one size fit all.

Comment: Why do you think that the clients wouldn't also support a WCF service using `basicHttpBinding`? There's not necessarily a reason to get stuck in the past.

Comment: Yeah, the client should be supporting it as well. The problem here is that some clients (which are already compiled) are always looking for the servicename.asmx. I don't have  control over the client code and if the Service is changed, it will break current clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I have a possible solution for you that is not award-winning for elegance but I've just tested it and it works.

You can expose one WebMethod that returns object and takes a params object[] parameter, allowing you to pass whatever you like to it (or nothing) and return whatever you want. This compiles to legal WSDL using the 'anyType' type.

If you can identify which actual method to call based on the number and datatype of parameters passed to this method, you can call the appropriate method and return whatever value you want.

The service: -

```
[WebMethod]
public object Method(params object[] parameters)
{
    object returnValue = null;

    if (parameters != null && parameters.Length != 0)
    { 
        if (parameters[0].GetType() == typeof(string) && parameters[1].GetType() == typeof(int))
        {
            return new ServiceImplementation().StringIntMethod(parameters[0].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(parameters[1]));
        }
        else if (parameters[0].GetType() == typeof(string) && parameters[1].GetType() == typeof(string))
        {
            return new ServiceImplementation2().StringStringMethod(parameters[0].ToString(), parameters[1].ToString());
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

My test service implementation classes: -

```
public class ServiceImplementation
{
    public string StringIntMethod(string someString, int someInt)
    {
        return "StringIntMethod called";
    }
}

public class ServiceImplementation2
{
    public float StringStringMethod(string someString, string someOtherString)
    {
        return 3.14159265F;
    }
}
```

An example of use: -

```
    var service = new MyTestThing.MyService.WebService1();

    object test1 = service.Method(new object[] { "hello", 3 });
    Console.WriteLine(test1.ToString());

    object test2 = service.Method(new object[] { "hello", "there" });
    Console.WriteLine(test2.ToString());
```

I've tested this and it works. If you're interested, the WSDL that "Method" generates: -

```
POST /test/WebService1.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/Method"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <Method xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <parameters>
        <anyType />
        <anyType />
      </parameters>
    </Method>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Incase you're wondering, yes I am bored at work and I'm in the mood for helping people :)

Comment: Thanks for spending your time here, I think this approach might work and I can write some script using AST to generate the WebMethods with the array of parameters. Actually depending on the parameters. Since I will have a configuration file with the version,I know what implementation to call. Thank you.

Comment: After some testing, I think that the problem is bigger. By looking at two different versions of the proxy (v1 and v3), I can see that in V3 some WebMethods were deleted and they were used in V1. If I use all the methods in version 3, then some other methods won't be available. Because clients are designed to consume some specific methods in the current API, the fact that each version adds complexity because WebMethods are deleted or added, I don't see any other option than generating the proxy at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

In short no, that is not possible. I was going to suggest using the webservice as a facade but by the sounds of it the method signatures on each version are different, which would make that more difficult.

If the client application is dependent on a particular version of your webservice, can't you just deploy all versions of your service with different names (i.e. servicev1.asmx, servicev2.asmx etc), and add some config to your client to tell it which one to call ?

Comment: Hello, well that could be another option.It would be an issue though if the clients are designed to always look for a specific service, then  this approach would not work (I mean, if the client is designed to always discover that service name). Because the Web Service is consumed by several clients in different technologies, I would test it anyway. Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Actually I was also thinking on creating a kind of router that should load the current class with the WebMethods exposed, but to be fair, I have not figure out how to do it yet.

Comment: Clients are "designed to always look for a specific service" - is the problem here that you do not have access to their source code ?